# Refund Ether stored in a Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, mist

i'm trying to store Ether inside a Contract and refund it when I call the function paypackEther(). Inside of the Remix IDE with the JavaScript VM it works perfectly, but when I execute it on Rinkeby with Mist, I can't get the stored ether. It's making me crazy...

What's my mistake?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SimpleContract {


function () public payable  {
}

constructor() payable  public {
}

function paybackEther() public  {
    selfdestruct(msg.sender);
}

}
```

The contract adress is: 0x0b5933fd3D33F7d79C0e19e12A070fafA053Df57
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0b5933fd3d33f7d79c0e19e12a070fafa053df57

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you give us a link to the rinkeby transaction where you tried and failed to get the ether back? Did the transaction revert, or fail silently?

Comment: Can you replace `selfdestruct(msg.sender)` with `msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance)` and say if it works?

Comment: @JesseBusman 
Here's the contract adress: 
0x0b5933fd3D33F7d79C0e19e12A070fafA053Df57

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0b5933fd3d33f7d79c0e19e12a070fafa053df57

The latest transaction is 0x70b1860a8f1c9f2ec002e737744198a83f8d8182c6b853895991ffceec6201f9

I also published the Code of the Contract in Etherscan, to make it easier to understand my code.

Comment: @goodvibration I also tried this solution, but it makes no difference. I've got my code from https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/contracts/Escrow.sol#L42 
This works perfect...

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at your transactions, and I see that you are not calling the `paybackEther()` function at all:

- [0x9afb64e3082d06e0915f7d89a2b436ae3f9f273630407b52662d3a5785933336](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9afb64e3082d06e0915f7d89a2b436ae3f9f273630407b52662d3a5785933336)
- [0xd70b7dae05ee903868fc9367f6a3795b76e0916597187c1fda31bbf3c655d321](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd70b7dae05ee903868fc9367f6a3795b76e0916597187c1fda31bbf3c655d321)
- [0x70b1860a8f1c9f2ec002e737744198a83f8d8182c6b853895991ffceec6201f9](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x70b1860a8f1c9f2ec002e737744198a83f8d8182c6b853895991ffceec6201f9)

All these transactions send 0 ether and 0 bytes of data to the contract. A call to `paybackEther()` would send 4 bytes of data to the contract.

You're most likely doing something wrong when trying to call the function in Mist. I don't know what, because I cannot look on your screen and see which buttons you are pressing :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me!
I tried it now on 3 different computers and indeed all the transactions have an input data of 0x.

I'm almost sure, the fault is within my code... All the computer show the same problem. And other contracts work without problems...  

Do you have any other advice for me?

Comment: For example I tried this code: https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/contracts/Escrow.sol#L42 (Contract Destructible, fuction destroy)

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer, but it's not very "clean":
It seems like Mist needs an input parameter in the function paybackEther...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SimpleContract {

bool public finished;

function () public payable  {
}

constructor() payable  public {
}

function paybackEther(bool newfinished) public  {

finished = newfinished;        
selfdestruct(msg.sender);
}

}
```